# Android SQL INSERT statement using variables problem

Tags: android, sql, insert

I have a problem with an SQL INSERT statement. I am trying to insert data stored in Strings but this always throws an error.

```
private final String HASH_DB = "hashDb";
private final String HASH_TABLE2 = "newHashes";

SQLiteDatabase hashDB = null;

hashDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(HASH_DB, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

hashDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + HASH_TABLE2
    + " (dialogID INT, Filename VARCHAR, Hash VARCHAR);");

hashDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + HASH_TABLE2 +" (dialogID, Filename, Hash) "
   + " Values (dialogID, filename, newHash);");
```

dialogID is an int, and Filename and Hash are both Strings, I have confirmed that the correct data is stored in these by displaying them in a Toast.

The above throws an error but if I change the last line to this below, i.e hardcoding the data to be inserted it works.

```
hashDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + HASH_TABLE2 +" (dialogID, Filename, Hash) "
   + " Values (4, 'filename', 'newHash');");
```

How can I get this working?

Many Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't really worked with Android, but are those files not files variables?

Shouldn't it be

```
hashDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + HASH_TABLE2 +" (dialogID, Filename, Hash) "
   + " Values (" + dialogID + ", '" + filename + "', '" + newHash + "');");
```

Comment: you are missing quotes around filename and newHash in the query

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the string quotes and add your variables on your Insert statement.  Something like this;

```
hashDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + HASH_TABLE2 +" (dialogID, Filename, Hash) "
   + " Values (" + dialogID + ", '" + filename + "', '" + newHash + "');");
```

Assuming you have the three variables (dialogID, filename and newHash) defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong the parameters to the query.

You should do this in the following way:

```
    " Values(" + dialogId +", " +filename +", " + newHash +");"
```

or you should use

```
    public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

Example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("dialogId", dialogId);
values.put("filename", filename);
values.put("newHash", newHash);
mDatabase.insert("your_table", null, values);
```